# How can I (or should I) call my Express API from my Express API?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm new to this Node and Express stuff. I've made one Rest API which allows a user to add a document to my database. I'm making another API which should do the same thing just with an array of documents to add. In the interest of not duplicating code, should I have it call the former API? Is this the conventional way to do things? The 2 API's are defined in their own controller files. If I want to re-use the code, one controller will have to know about the other - is that okay? Also, I'd have to make my own req, res, and err objects and give it to the other controller function. It doesn't seem intuitive to me. I'm just wondering what's the convention for this?

Comment: Can you share your express code? This will be a big help. Thanks

Comment: You can just create a single shared function that adds an array of documents.  From the API that adds a single document, just create an array, put that single document in the array and call your shared function.  From the API that adds an array, just call the shared function directly, passing it the array you already have.  Usually, there is no need to go back to the web server just to do what can be accomplished with an internal function call.  For APIs this similar, they should probably in the same file so they can share the common implementation.  But, you could share the common func too.